# determine the limit of sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, probability-limit-theorems

Need help on how to determine the limits, if it exists for this sequence. Have no idea where to start. Thanks in advance smart people!

> $$A_n = \dfrac {(n+2)^{2n}}{(n^2-n-6)^n}$$

Comment: limits? Do you mean $n\to 0$, $n\to\infty$,...

Comment: The OP called $A_n$ a sequence so the limit is at $\infty$@pisoir

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane What about sequence that goes to $-\infty$? The question needs a little clarification in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

hint:
$$A_n=\frac{(n+2)^{2n}}{(n^2-n-6)^n}=\left(\frac{(n+2)(n+2)}{(n+2)(n-3)}\right)^n$$
$$=\left(\frac{n+2}{n-3}\right)^n=\left(\frac{1+2/n}{1-3/n}\right)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n=\frac{(n+2)^{2n}}{(n^2-n-6)^n}=\frac{(1+\frac 4 n+\frac 4{n^2})^{n}}{(1-\frac1n-\frac6{n^2})^n}$$
so $$\log(a_n)=n\left(\log\left(1+\frac 4 n+\frac 4{n^2}\right)-\log\left(1-\frac1n-\frac6{n^2}\right)\right)\sim_\infty n\left(\frac 4 n+\frac 1n\right)=5$$
so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=e^5$$

Comment: Hello, Sami! Hope you're well!

Answer (score 1):

Write $A_n = \left( (n+2)^2/(n^2-n-6) \right)^n = \left( (n+2)/(n-3) \right)^n = \left( (n-3+5)/(n-3)\right)^n = \left(1 + 5/(n-3)\right)^n$.

This limit should look familiar.